# how to replace one specific string in whole string

Tags: java

How to append namespace for every workspace in result string .so final output will be

```
  String namespace = "@{XYZ/1.0}categories:";
            String result= "(\"workspace://123456\" AND \"workspace://55757575\")";

            (@{XYZ/1.0}categories:"workspace://123456" AND @{XYZ/1.0}categories:"workspace://55757575");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using `replaceAll`?

```
result.replaceAll("\\\"workspace:", namespace + "\"workspace:");
```